# Principal disjunctive normal form conversion problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am solving a question where I have to convert $(\neg P \ \lor Q)$ this equation into principal disjonction normal form. so far I know that to convert it I have to multiply 1 with it. ie; $(\neg P \ \lor Q) \land T$, where $T$ is true.
now in the solution of the question after multiplying the equation with 1 it is written like this.
$(\neg P \ \lor Q) \land (\neg P \ \lor P)$.
so my question is why $(\neg P \ \lor P)$ is coming why can't we write $(P \ \lor \neg Q)$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(P \ \lor \neg P)$ is exactly true. I guess the solution wants to express the normal form uniquely with elements of the original logical proposition (*i.e* $P$ and $Q$), and avoids using other symbols (such as $T$). This is why they are using $(P \ \lor \neg P)$.

Moreover, note that $(\neg P \ \lor Q) \land (P \ \lor \neg Q) \neq (\neg P \ \lor Q)$. For example, take $P$ False and $Q$ True.

Comment: where are you getting those exact negation symbol from I don't have that symbol on my keyboard. By the way thanks for the edit and the elaborated explanation.

Comment: @AtanuMondal you should have a look at latex (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) :) to do the exact negation symbol I type `$\neg$`. Btw by clicking on edit below my answer you can see exactly what I typed.